# REST Framework Retrieved Wrong Data

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I was just getting started on using Django's rest framework. The problem I faced is that Rest Framework didn't fetch from the right URL: I want it to get the list of Todos but it returned the URL where the API was located.

(Might be easy for many of you, but I am completely fresh to drf)

*serializers*

```py
from .models import Todo
from rest_framework import serializers

class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'desc', 'level', 'created']
```

*urls*

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='todo_all'),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

*views*

```py
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Todo
from .serializers import TodoSerializer

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "todo/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['todos'] = Todo.objects.all()
        return context

class TodoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
```

What I want Rest to get:

[image]

What Rest actually displayed:

[image]

Like, I want the data of the todos, not the URL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`. Try to use `ModelSerializer` instead.

```
from .models import Todo
from rest_framework import serializers

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['title', 'desc', 'level', 'created']
```